# placeholder com mesmo nome da Label

Tags: html, placeholder

Como faço para o placeholder pegar o mesmo nome que está na minha label ?

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<label for="sing_pass" class="label_pass"><span class="lang" key ="Text33">Code Activation</span></label>
                          <input type="text" id="sing_pass" class="input" placeholder="Code Activation ">
```

Gostaria que o placeholder mudasse sempre que a label mudasse.

Comment: Só com Html, impossível, precisa de Javascript para isto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É preciso usar JavaScript para isso. Como o atributo `for` aponta para a `id` do `input`, você pode alterar o `placeholder` do campo pegando o texto da `label` onde o `for` do primeiro é igual ao `id` do segundo.

O código abaixo irá percorrer todos os `label`, pegar o valor do `for`, buscar um elemento que tenha o `id` igual ao valor do `for` e aplicar o `placeholder` com o respectivo texto da `label`:

```js
const labels = document.querySelectorAll("label[for]")
for(let i of labels){
   let el = document.getElementById(i.getAttribute("for"));
   if(el) el.placeholder = i.textContent;
}
```

```html
<label for="sing_pass" class="label_pass"><span class="lang" key ="Text33">Code Activation</span></label>
<input type="text" id="sing_pass" class="input">

<label for="teste" class="label_pass"><span class="lang" key ="Text33">Qualquer coisa</span></label>
<input type="text" id="teste" class="input">
```

Se for apenas um elemento, fica mais simples:

```js
document.getElementById("sing_pass")
.placeholder = document.querySelector("[for='sing_pass']").textContent;
```

```html
<label for="sing_pass" class="label_pass"><span class="lang" key ="Text33">Code Activation</span></label>
<input type="text" id="sing_pass" class="input">
```

Answer (score 4):

É possível fazer isso via JQuery, ficaria mais ou menos assim.
   Exemplo funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/fj3x7sgq/1/

```
<label for="sing_pass" class="label_pass">
    <span class="lang" key ="Text33">Label</span>
    <input type="text" id="sing_pass" class="input">
    </label>


   <script> 
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var place = $('.label_pass').find('.lang').text();
         $('#sing_pass').attr('placeholder', place)
       }); 
   </script>
```